# Image galleries in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

I'm wondering what the best design for the following would look like in Rails:

A website with three different image galleries, let's say one showing pictures of the company's staff under `mywebsite.com/gallery`, another one shows pictures of product A at `mywebsite.com/productA` and the third shows product B under `mywebsite.com/productB`.

I assume it would be bad design to create a gallery resource, along with a productA and a productB resource since there will be only one of each and it's really the new photos and not new image collections which will have to be created.

So I'm thinking if it's a good idea to create an images resource and then use single table inheritance, instantiate a gallery_images, productA_images and productB_images and change the routes to the respective ones which I want to show up as URLs. I should probably mention that I don't want to mix up the images for the different sections.

I feel there must be a "proper" way of doing this, I guess tons of websites use a similar scheme.

Comment: Just to give us more context, at what exact "level" are you interested in? I mean, do you want a "proper" way of doing it in OOP sense, in Rails common practices or the 3 tier architecture? Because, they would result different answers.

Comment: I'm interested in the "Rails way" but actually it would be really interesting if you could briefly point out the differences between your options or where to dig deeper into the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Not to say that this is a "Rails way", but I've seen it done as follows in most of the Rails projects I had access to. Basically, when it comes to galleries, you would want to let customer upload and manage the images. So, you would use [gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_file_uploads) like [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave). Once you choose one of these gems, your class design is predefined. You'd have a model that has an attachment.

Then, you would simply initialize a specific instance of your model (or a model with *has-many* attachment model association) and simply render a list of image URLs in your HTML template. The actual gallery is then styled and brought to live on frontend using CSS and JS.

---

As for the difference between other contexts. Let's say OOP. If you are looking for the "correct" way of doing it in OOP context, you would first have to consider your business domain. And design your classes so that they reflect your business requirements (taking into account all OOP principles). A best way to start this journey would possibly be learning and understanding OOP principles and forgetting that "*Circle extends Shape, Rectangle extends Shape and this is what OOP is!*" kind of mentality. Design patterns are actually a good example of what you end up with if you follow OOP principles. [Head First DP](http://amzn.to/27KKF9f) is a good introductory book.